# Why are certain manufacturing locations being yellowish and blurred in azure maps?

Tags: azure-maps

I'm working in IOT map visualization project. Some of our manufacturing locations are appearing yellowish and blurred upon zoom. What is the reason ? We rely on the maps clarity upon zoom to identify the exact locations of the IOT devices.

Comment: Can you provide an example location. There is a lot of possible reasons.

Comment: Thanks ! Please find one of our Location coordinates Latitude= 41.175561996906225 & longitude=1.223645372371732.

Comment: Looks like this is in regards to aerial imagery. I suspect the cause is that newer imagery from a different provider is being prioritized over old imagery that had higher resolution. I recommend raising a ticket with the Azure support team so they can look into this and see if it makes sense to switch back.